# Why are `drush pm-list` & `drush pm-updatestatus` disabling the default theme?

Tags: drush

I have a Drupal 7 site with 3 themes enabled:

- Foo
- Adminimal
- Shiny

Foo is a custom theme for the front-end, located in `/sites/foo/themes/` and set as the default.

Adminimal and Shiny are both installed via `drush make` into `sites/all/themes/contrib/`.

Running `drush pm-updatestatus` disables the default 'Foo' theme.

```
$ drush pm-updatestatus
Checking available update data ...                             [ok]
Failed to check available update data for Foo settings.        [ok]
Checked available update data for Administration menu.         [ok]
...
Checked available update data for Adminimal.                   [ok]
Checked available update data for Shiny.                       [ok]
Failed to get available update data for one project.           [error]
Checked available update data for 64 projects.                 [status]
 Name                                                        Installed Version  Proposed version  Message
 Administration menu Adminimal Theme (adminimal_admin_menu)  7.x-1.6            7.x-1.7           Update available
...
 Adminimal (adminimal_theme)                                 7.x-1.21           7.x-1.24          Update available
 Shiny (shiny)                                               7.x-1.6            7.x-1.7           Update available
```

The `Failed to check available update data for Foo settings.` & `Failed to get available update data for one project. [error]` lines from the output clearly look relevant, but I'm struggling to identify the underlying cause.

With the Drush's `-d` debug flag enabled the output includes this line before the `Failed to get update data for on project [error]`:

```
Undefined index: foo theme.inc:100 [1.78 sec, 35.7 MB]            [notice]
```

`drush pm-list` has the same effect.

Presumably there's something wrong with the declaration, or location of the Foo theme?

Checking the status report via the Drupal admin does not disable the Foo theme.

Why would `drush pm-list` & `drush pm-updatestatus` disable the default theme?

Comment: pm-updatestatus queries the Drupal servers for updated versions of modules. If this is a custom module, Drupal has no response from it: `Failed to get update data for on project [error]`. So this is normal for custom modules or themes. It should however not disable the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your themes for Drupal 7 should live here:

- `/sites/all/themes/THEMENAME` - for all sites and all themes
- `/sites/example.com/themes/THEMENAME` - for example.com of a multisite setup

Now in your case there is an additional note: You have the option to put your theme in a `contrib` and a `custom` subfolder. Themes in the custom subfolder would be skipped during the update process (see [/r/drupal](https://www.reddit.com/r/drupal/comments/1kqbsd/remove_custom_drupal_modules_and_themes_from_the/) for cross reference). There is a caveat though: Apparently once you use `contrib`you also *have to* use `custom` otherwise it seems the whole tree breaks (see [disqus](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/pixelite/remove_custom_drupal_modules_and_themes_from_the_update_status_page/#comment-1008134893))

Try to move the foo theme too: `/sites/all/themes/custom/foo` or `/sites/example.com/themes/custom/foo` then run `drush rr` and `drush cc all`

Comment: Hi @nhck, thanks for your help. I moved the theme to `/sites/all/themes/custom/foo` and ran `drush rr` and `drush cc all` as you suggested, but it hasn't resolved the issue. Both `pm-list` and `pm-updatestatus` are still disabling the Foo theme.

Comment: Through trial and error we've identified that setting the `--uri=foo.example.com` flag seems to prevent `pm-list` and `pm-updatestatus` from disabling the theme. Is setting the `--uri` flag mandatory for multisite? I haven't been able to find anything in Drush's documentation indicating that it is.

Comment: This article explains why setting `--uri` is significant for multisite, though it does not explain why `pm-list` and `pm-updatestatus` would disable the default theme when Drush is passed insufficient information to identify the multisite site. https://docs.acquia.com/articles/how-use-drush-multisite-installation

Comment: Interessting. Sorry that my answer wasn't sufficient. I've been wondering it there might be something in the info file of your theme that could make drush look for a project on drupal.org?

Comment: I had thought the same, but it looks very vanilla to me: http://pastebin.com/S4qpfBNm